# Json object with nested objects, nested objects | mockable

Tags: json

I'm trying to create a test API in mockable.

**What am I trying to create?**

I'm trying to build an Json object with a Nested object which holds another nested object.

*Example for use: store object => Store info => product list*

**What I expect to create**

```
{
    "Object": {
            "id": 0, 
            "name": "Nova", 
            "nestedObject": {
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "NestedNestedObject1",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "NestedNestedObject2",
                },
}
```

**Result I'm getting:**

```
Error: Parse error on line 11:
...: {                {                  
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

At NestedNestedObject2

How do I create a nested, nested object? If I'm correct mockable accepts pure Json

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object". [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an object or an array). Most languages provide a way to generate JSON from a native data structure. All you have to do is to build the data structure. The text you posted is not JSON. The value associated with the key `nestedObject` should probably be an array (`[...]`) not an object (`{...}`). Do not write code that generates JSON; use the support provided by your language or its libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to create and that depends on your API. The actual problem is that your JSON is not valid.

After your `nestedObject` there is just a `{` and that is wrong. In this case I assume you want to have an array of `nestedObject` (and perhaps also name should be `nestedObjects`) so fix would be (see the array `[]`):

```
{
    "Object": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Nova",
        "nestedObject": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "NestedNestedObject1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "NestedNestedObject2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```